# Property requires fields to be named error in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, payumoney

I am using one third party SDK, where there are some variables declared as

[image]

I have clean and build the project and also erased the derived data, still i'm getting this error.

How to get rid off this issue?

Comment: Might be these are surl and furl.

Comment: I have also tried that, it gives me an error at runtime say "[PayUModelPaymentParams setSurl:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc5e4406cc0"

Comment: send screenshot to their support team. they will tell.

Comment: Check for bad white space. There are unicode characters that look like space but are not. Just remove the spaces between `*` and `SURL` and try compiling again.

Comment: I tried that @LGP, still it gives me the same error

Comment: Also if I am giving SUURL or some other name it is not showing an error, but the error comes only when the variable name is SURL and FURL. First it didn't shown any error but for the past few builds only I am getting error like this. Why the behaviour of code is like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found were I am wrong,

I have done a stupid thing that I installed a SDK through cocoapods
 and also used the same SDK by drag and drop, so the same properties repeated twice in my code leads to this error.

Thank you for your suggestions.